# Is there a way to package a Siri Shortcut Automation as part of my iOS App?

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I have created a `Siri Automation` from `Shortcuts` app. Like, everytime the user opens Music app, it redirects to Safari. *This was just for the purpose of experimentation*. Can this be "Packaged" in a swift app that I am creating?

Basically, I want something like an **Install Automation** button in my app, that will install this automation (with user's permission, of course) to the user?

Answer (score -1):

One way I can think of is by sharing this new shortcut as an iCloud link - https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/share-shortcuts-apdf01f8c054/ios

Having an icloud link, your app can request Safari to open this link and then the user can install it by clicking on "Get Shortcut".

So yeah, a pretty straightforward way I think.